# Is there a way of retaining specific occurences within a nested JSON whilst removing others using JOLT "remove"

Tags: java, json, jolt

I have a nested JSON of a similar structure to the following, that I am performing a number of transformations on.

Currently, I have this as an input:

```json
{
  "LEVEL_0": {
    "RANDOM_FIELD_A": "1234",
    "LEVEL_1": {
      "RANDOM_FIELD_B": null,
      "RANDOM_FIELD_C": "DEEZ",
      "LEVEL_2": {
        "RANDOM_FIELD_D": "12345",
        "RANDOM_FIELD_E": "CHUPAPI",
        "LEVEL_3A": {
          "RANDOM_FIELD_F": 800
        },
        "RANDOM_FIELD_G": null,
        "LEVEL_3B": [
          {
            "RANDOM_FIELD_H": "12345671",
            "RANDOM_FIELD_I": "DONUT",
            "LEVEL_4": [
              {
                "FIELD_1": "CRISPY",
                "FIELD_2": "CREME",
                "FIELD_3": "CHEESE",
                "FIELD_4": "CAKE",
                "FIELD_5": 123456789,
                "FIELD_6": "COCONUT"
              },
              {
                "FIELD_1": "UNCLE",
                "FIELD_2": "BENS",
                "FIELD_3": "FIRED",
                "FIELD_4": "RICE",
                "FIELD_5": 987654321,
                "FIELD_6": "FLAMINGO"
              },
              {
                "FIELD_1": "IN",
                "FIELD_2": "THE",
                "FIELD_3": "JUNGLE",
                "FIELD_4": "THE",
                "FIELD_5": 345453643,
                "FIELD_6": "MIGHTY"
              },
              {
                "FIELD_1": "THIS",
                "FIELD_2": "IS",
                "FIELD_3": "THE",
                "FIELD_4": "LAST",
                "FIELD_5": 344,
                "FIELD_6": "ONE"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want this for the output:

```json
{
  "LEVEL_0": {
    "RANDOM_FIELD_A": "1234",
    "LEVEL_1": {
      "RANDOM_FIELD_C": "DEEZ",
      "LEVEL_2": {
        "RANDOM_FIELD_E": "CHUPAPI",
        "LEVEL_3A": {
          "RANDOM_FIELD_F": 800
        },
        "RANDOM_FIELD_G": null,
        "LEVEL_3B": [
          {
            "RANDOM_FIELD_I": "DONUT",
            "LEVEL_4": [
              {
                "FIELD_1": "CRISPY",
                "FIELD_2": "CREME",
                "FIELD_4": "CAKE",
                "FIELD_6": "COCONUT"
              },
              {
                "FIELD_1": "UNCLE",
                "FIELD_2": "BENS",
                "FIELD_4": "RICE",
                "FIELD_6": "FLAMINGO"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the JOLT library and want to know how to reduce the "LEVEL_4" array to 2 occurences instead of 4, whilst also removing "FIELD_3" AND "FIELD_5". I want to always retain the first 2 occurences regardless of whether there are 4 or 5 or 6 occurences, as this could be the case from the input.

I have a remove operation that can remove the required fields, i.e. "FIELD_3" AND "FIELD_4" but it retains all 4 occurences. I need this to be done using a JOLT 'remove'.

What I currently have is:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "LEVEL_0": {
        "LEVEL_1": {
          "RANDOM_FIELD_B": "",
          "LEVEL_2": {
            "RANDOM_FIELD_D": "",
            "LEVEL_3B": {
              "*": {
                "RANDOM_FIELD_H": "",
                "LEVEL_4": {
                  "*": {
                    "FIELD_3": "",
                    "FIELD_5": ""
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a **shift** transformation which filters out by the sub-indexes (**0** and **1**) of the concerned array such that

```json
{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "LEVEL_0": {
      "LEVEL_1": {
        "*": "&2.&1.&",
        "LEVEL_2": {
          "*": "&3.&2.&1.&",
          "LEVEL_3B": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&5.&4.&3.&2[&1].&",
              "LEVEL_4": {
                "0|1": {
                  "@": "&7.&6.&5.&4[&3].&2[&1]"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or through use of **remove** transformation which will include a bit hardcoding by adding conditional `"2|3|4|5": ""`(*the number of the integers may vary depending on the number of the nested objects*) as the else case to the present input spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "LEVEL_0": {
        "LEVEL_1": {
          "RANDOM_FIELD_B": "",
          "LEVEL_2": {
            "RANDOM_FIELD_D": "",
            "LEVEL_3B": {
              "*": {
                "RANDOM_FIELD_H": "",
                "LEVEL_4": {
                  "2|3|4|5": "",
                  "*": {
                    "FIELD_3": "",
                    "FIELD_5": ""
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

since `"*"` wildcard cannot be considered as the else case representative as it removes all attributes of the objects

Comment: Is there no way of doing this without using a shift? I already have transformations in place after the remove, so adding a shift would be inconvenient. Doing this directly from the remove operation would be ideal.